# How to delete large volumes of data from ElasticSearch efficiently?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch index (or better to say: 1 alias pointing to ±30 indices) with 4.2 billion documents in them. I now want to delete a specific subset of them using a filter.

When I count the documents that adhere to that filter, I get back 2.3 million. Determining this is done in around 1 second. When I delete them naively using `delete_by_query` however, I hit various circuit breaking exceptions.

I then learned about `slices=auto` and `wait_for_completion=false` from the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html). I now run the deletion in the background, and check regularly if the deletion task is finished. It does seem to be stable (which is the most important to me), but it takes around 1.5 to 2 hours to delete it all.

Is there a more optimal way to delete this amount of data from an index? (where for me optimal firstly means stable/robust and secondly means fast).

Answer (score 1):

`delete_by_query` is always relatively slow

- it creates snapshots in background (maybe that's why circuit breakers got triggered?)
- it retries 10 times on conflicts (important e.g. if documents get frequent updates)
- it has throttling by default, to keep impact on cluster low

What you can optimize

- Target only those indices that really contain your deletable data
- Go index by index, not all 30 at once
- Adjust or disable throttling, if your cluster can handle larger deletion loads (and load of merging the segments with lots of soft-deleted documents afterwards)
- If you can identify whole indices that contain only deletable data, dropping (or removing from alias) them would be for sure faster
- Redesign the system so that it would be possible to drop whole indices, not using delete_by_query
- If an index has mostly deletable data, it could be faster to d othe opposite: reindexing it into another index, copying only the useful data, then dropping the old index / removing from alias
- If version conflicts are appearing (e.g. because document was updated since start of the delete-by-query) and conflicts are not important, set conflicts: proceed (be aware, that means the conflicting documents will not be deleted, you need to check the results if conflicts actually happened, and retry the delete-by-query)

Comment: Interesting thinking. I have a follow-up question about the first two points. Do you mean looping over the 30 individual indices, first checking if there are any documents to delete in them, and if so, delete it from this index only? I can of course automate this, but if that is better, then why is ElasticSearch not doing this under the hood?

Comment: The idea behind checking which index has your data was to avoid unnecessary snapshots (i don't know if elasticsearch does such a check internally beforehand). Or if the count of such documents is low, you could delete them yourself with a bulk, if that makes a difference.

Comment: The idea behind going index by index was to do it in a more controlled manner, as you say stability is your main concern. My assumption is that elasticsearch would choke on the sheer amount of work to do and trip over the circuit breakers. Though I cannot prove that.